# Android getMap() returns null finding map with play services 7.3 (returns ok with play services 7.0)

Tags: android, google-maps

Android getMap() returns null with play services 7.3 in one phone (returns ok with play services 7.0 and other phones)

phone

fonepad 6. Android version 4.2.2

google play services version:

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.3.0'
```

XML:

```
<fragment
    android:id="@+id/mi_mapa"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    />
```

Java:

```
MiAplicacion.mMap = ((MapFragment) ((Activity) MiAplicacion.context).getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.mi_mapa).getMap();
```

mMap returns null in fonepad. In 2 other phones tested and emulator it works ok.

With play services version:

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.0.0'
```

It works Ok in all the phones tested, including fonepad.

any idea of what is happening?
Could this be a bug of play services 7.3.0? 
I can't find any explanation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[MapFragment.getMap()](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/MapFragment.html#getMap()) is deprecated, and has been for some time now:

> This method is deprecated.
>
> Use getMapAsync(OnMapReadyCallback) instead. The callback method provides you with a GoogleMap instance guaranteed to be non-null and ready to be used.

Use **getMapAsync(OnMapReadyCallback)** instead:

```
getMapAsync(new OnMapReadyCallback() {
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        // ...
    }
});
```

Comment: This worked out well. When I used this method , the phone has updated google play services , but he did not before, when I used the deprecated method.

Thank you very much

Comment: Glad it worked. Feel free to accept my answer then ;)